# AWS static website apex domain returns 403, www subdomain works fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, cname

I am creating a static website with AWS S3, CloudFront, Route 53, and AWS Certificate Manger. The www subdomain of my website (https://www.lnkrecall.org/) works fine, but the apex domain does not:

- http://lnkrecall.org/ returns `403 ERROR The request could not be satisfied.` and does not redirect to HTTPS as it should.
- https://lnkrecall.org/ displays `This site can’t provide a secure connection` in Google Chrome

Configuration details:

- The certificate I created in AWS Certificate Manager covers both `lnkrecall.org` and `*.lnkrecall.org`
- In Route 53, there is one A record for each of `lnkrecall.org` and `www.lnkrecall.org` that both point to the same `...cloudfront.net.` distribution
- That distribution lists the www subdomain as a CNAME and has a Protocol Policy of `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS`

Evidently the apex domain is somehow configured differently from the subdomain, but I can't spot it

Comment: " www subdomain as a CNAME" - what about `lnkrecall.org`? Its not in your CF distro as altenrative domain?

Comment: It wasn't, because I was under the impression that it wasn't necessary. But having added it, I see that it is. Thank you! I'd mark your answer correct if you want to post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that apex domain was not added to CF distribution as an alternative name.

The solution was to add the domain to CF distribution.